# AngularJS - Passing select list value to function returning undefined

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have 3 select lists that I'm trying to pass the selected value over to a function.

```js
  $scope.mapSelections = function(location) {

    var filteredPins = [];

    console.log('location:' + location);
          
            var region = (location ? location.location.Region : '');
      var state = (location ? location.state.StateName : '');
      var city = (location ? location.city.CityName : '');

    $scope.dataObject.forEach(function(itemElement, itemIndex) {
      itemElement.Locations.forEach(function(locationElement, locationIndex) {
        if (locationElement.Region === region || !region) {
          locationElement.Sites.forEach(function(siteElement, siteIndex) {
            if ((siteElement.State == state && !city) || siteElement.City == city || (!state && !city)) {
              filteredPins.push(siteElement);
              // console.table(filteredPins)
              return false;
            }
          });
        }
      });
    });

    $scope.filteredPins = filteredPins;
    $scope.zoomToIncludeMarkers();

  };
```

```html
<column>
  <select name="selectRegion" class="form-control" ng-model="selectRegion" ng-change="regionSelected(); mapSelections(location.Region)" ng-options="location as location.Region for location in locationObject | orderBy: location.Region:reverse track by location.Region">
    <option value="">Select Region</option>
  </select>

  <select name="selectState" class="form-control" ng-disabled="!selectRegion" ng-model="selectState" ng-change="mapSelections(state.StateName)" ng-options="state as state.StateName for state in selectRegion.States | unique: 'state.StateName' | orderBy: 'StateName' ">
    <option value="">{{regionSelectMsg}}</option>
  </select>

  <select name="selectCity" class="form-control" ng-disabled="!selectState" ng-model="selectCity" ng-change="mapSelections(city.CityName)" ng-options="city as city.CityName for city in selectState.Cities | unique: 'city.CityName' | orderBy: 'CitytName' ">
    <option value="">Select City</option>
  </select>
</column>
```

I am wanting to pass the value of select list selection to the mapSelections function in the ng-change, at which point it will be used in the nested forEach loop to get the values from the model and push it to a new array.

Trying to pass the ng-model of each select list to the function results in an undefined on that value. I've also tried using the iterators in the ng-repeat (location.Region, state.StateName and city.CityName) with no success.

See Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/qaLFYD?p=preview

Comment: Can you make a demo on plunkr? Does that console.log work/

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/qaLFYD?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass in the `ngModel` of the `select` - not the `ngOptions` syntax:

```
<select name="selectRegion" class="form-control" ng-model="selectRegion" ng-change="regionSelected(); mapSelections(selectRegion)" ng-options="location as location.Region for location in locationObject | orderBy: location.Region:reverse track by location.Region">
    <option value="">Select Region</option>
</select>
```

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/jvuX5cbrPIFUTTrWFJsD?p=preview